# cloudformation change parameters in template in stack which state is UPDATE_FAILED

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a stack with state UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED because one of my nested stack failed

```
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:074418685182:stack/ap-DEV-10-ResRootStackServerI-ETMCY1BACYOL/2d7805d0-3ba3-11ea-856c-02433c861a1c was not successfully updated. Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED with reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [ResServerFrontServerA, ResServerBackServerB, ResServerFrontServerB, ResServerBackServerA].
```

I know what is the problem - some of the instances have wrong instance type, after receiving this message I changed type of instance and the instances work correctly but my Cloudformation stack have the problem and I can't update because of this error. I tried run "continue update rollback" via AWS console but instances are changing because template has defined WRONG type of instance. How to change parameters in the existing template which stack is already run?

I tried ran command via cli

```
aws cloudformation continue-update-rollback --stack-name ap-DEV-10 --resources-to-skip ap-DEV-10-ResRootStackServerI-ETMCY1BACYOL.ResServerBackServerA
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
Nested stack resources can only be skipped when their embedded stack statuses are one of [DELETE_COMPLETE, DELETE_IN_PROGRESS, DELETE_FAILED]
```

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Same issue here too, if you have any clues or anything I'd be so happy to find a solution together.